# Render as html from a remote link on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

On my registration form i want to show a modal (of twitter-bootstrap) when the user has a successfull signup to tell him to check his email so i put "remote: true" on my form and render a .js.erb wich shows the modal, on my controller.

BUT, in case of inputs errors i need to render the page as html to refresh de form showing those errors.

Can I call the controller from the remote form as JS but render as html? (or any other idea to do what i want)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I supose that you have something like this in your controller:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :this }
    format.js { render :that }
  end
```

You could control errors im params before the respond_to block, and if there are any errors render your html view, else proceed to the respond_to block

```
  if errors?(params)
    render :error_view
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :this }
      format.js { render :that }
    end
  end
```